Animated split flap like carousel in OpenSCAD
Using OpenSCAD I want to create an animated and spinning Split Flap display spool.
Here is what I came up with so far:
width = 50;
height = 40;
bracket = 3;
thickness = 1;
diameter = 40;
flaps = 50;

module flap() {
    {
        cube([width,height,thickness], center = true);
        translate([ (width/2) + (bracket/2), -(height/2) + (bracket/2), 0]) 
            cube([bracket,bracket,thickness], center = true);
        translate([-(width/2) - (bracket/2), -(height/2) + (bracket/2), 0]) 
            cube([bracket,bracket,thickness], center = true);
    }
}

module rotating_flaps()
{
    rotate([0, 270, 90])
    {
        rotate([0, -360 * $t, 0])
        {
            for(i=[1:flaps])
            {
                translate([
                            (diameter)*sin(i*(360/flaps)),
                            0, 
                            (diameter)*cos(i*(360/flaps))
                          ])
                {
                    rotate([0, 360 * $t, 0])
                    {
                        rotate([0, 0, 90]) flap();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

module static_flaps()
{
    rotate([0, 0, 180])
    {
        // top flaps
        for(i=[0:flaps/2-1])
        {
            rotate([360/flaps * i, 0, 0])
            {
                translate([0, diameter, height/2])
                {
                    rotate([90, 0, 180])
                    {
                        flap();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // bottom flaps
        for(i=[1:flaps/2])
        {
            translate([0, diameter*cos(-360/flaps*i), diameter*sin(-360/flaps*i) - (diameter / 2)])
            {
                rotate([-90, 0, 180])
                {
                    flap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The module "rotating_flaps" shows an example of the rotating flaps as it should be. However, the upper half of the carousel shows the flaps incorrect, they should be tilted. The module "static_flaps" shows the flaps in correct arrangement but not rotating. In order to do that, I need to distinguish between the upper and the lower half of the flaps.
How can I do that?
